# how to merge 2 tables into single(side by side) table in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have two tables

Table 1:

```
name   sex    age
snr    m       22
kkk    f       23
djj    m       33
kkk    f       66
```

Table 2:

```
address  country
hyd      india
Ny       US
london   Uk
```

neither table has a common key. how can I get a single table by arranging above two table side by side like below?

Expected output:

```
name   sex    age    address   country
snr    m      22     hyd       india
kkk    f      23     Ny        US
djj    m      33     london    Uk
kkk    f      66
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you please put a little more effort into formatting and spelling and making your question clear in the future? I think I speak for most SO users that, while we don't mind making edits for clarity, putting next to zero effort into asking a question certainly doesn't make us want to help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your join can be very reliable, especially if your table lengths don't match up.

that said, it's definitely possible. before you begin, add both tables to the analysis using whatever method works for you.

---

### Step 1: Create a common key

in order to join tables you'll need some kind of common key. we can create one on the fly using the `RowId()` function, which the number (id) of the row.

1. from the **Insert** menu, choose **Transformations...**
2. select **Calculate new column** and click **Add..**
3. give the expression `RowId()` and name the column something like `RowId`
4. repeat these steps for each table in the analysis.

**note** that you need to do this via column transformation. transformations are calculated when a table is added/refreshed to the analysis, whereas calculated columns are evaluated as needed (basically). any join in Spotfire requires the transformation columns' more "static" nature; you will not be able to join on calculated columns.

### Step 2: Join the tables

so here we do the actual join.

1. from the **Insert** menu, choose **Columns...**
2. make sure your *left* table ('Table 1' above) is selected
3. select your *right* table ('Table 2') by clicking **Select ▼** and choosing it from **From Current Analysis**
4. click **Next >**
5. select our `RowId` column on both sides and click **Match Selected**, then click **Next >**
6. select whichever columns you want to add
7. choose **Full Outer Join** as the join method
8. finally, click **Finish**

your result matches your expected output.

---

if you have gaps in your data (empty rows in either left or right table) your data will almost certainly be misaligned as I believe Spotfire completely will ignore any blank rows. I don't think this it's really recommended to need to join like this without a common key, so if you have trouble with mismatches, you may want to reevaluate your data situation.